# Error with plm(); replacement has 2473 rows, data has 2475

Tags: r, regression, na, plm

I have my data-frame ***Alist500HB1***, 10 variables i.e date, cls, log ROA, Log TA etc. I am running a simple panel regression.

```
plm(Alist500HB1$`Log Q`~Alist500HB1$`CLASSIFIED_BOARD_SYSTEM`+Alist500HB1$`Log TA`+Alist500HB1$`Log ROA`+Alist500HB1$`Log Capex`+Alist500HB1$`onethirdRD`+Alist500HB1$`RD dummy `+Alist500HB1$`onethirdInsider`+Alist500HB1$`PCT_FLT_SHARES_INSTITUTIONS`+Alist500HB1$`onethirdsalesgrowth`+Alist500HB1$`TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_ASSET`+Alist500HB1$`Logprofit margin`+Alist500HB1$`onethirdassetgrowth`+Alist500HB1$`Log Age`,
    data = `Alist500HB1`, index=c("GICS"), model = "random"
)
```

When I running the regression I am getting this:

> Error in [[<-.data.frame(*tmp*, time.name, value = c(1L, 2L, 3L,
>   4L,  :    replacement has 2473 rows, data has 2475

I understand some posts saying this is due to the `N/A` data, however, I don't wish to clean them up (if so i can do `data <- na.omit(data))` but this will largely reduce my sample size which I don't want to see.

Can someone please give any suggestion how to deal with this? Should I keep cleaning `NA` data or other reasons?

Many thanks

Here is the screenshot of the data: [image]

Comment: This is impossible to tell without a reproducible example or with your data. Are you using the most recent version of plm?

Comment: Could you please see the attached sample data?

Comment: Well... screenshot data. Could you please see this thread about a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example